# Difference between non-collinear systems and paramagnetic ones?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, spinors

Non-collinear magnetism and paramagnetism, are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

No, [non-collinear magnetism](http://www.mariecurie.org/annals/volume4/phy3.pdf) is more related to [ferromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) and [anti-ferromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiferromagnetism) in that there is a set orientation of magnetic moments even absent an applied field, but unlike ferromagnetism and anti-ferromagnetism the spins are oriented neither parallel nor anti-parallel, for example in a [helical pattern](https://mysite.wsu.edu/personal/cwzhang/Shared%20Documents/presentation/multiferroics.pdf).  In [paramagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism), spins are randomly oriented absent an applied field, but orient when a field is applied.